# How to use Mobx createObservableArray with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mobx

Attempt #1:

```
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { createObservableArray, IObservableArray } from "mobx/lib/internal";
export class Example1 {
    @observable items : IObservableArray<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }
}
```

Result:

> Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type
>   'IObservableArray': spliceWithArray, observe, intercept,
>   clear, and 4 more.ts(2740)

Attempt #2:

```
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { createObservableArray, IObservableArray } from "mobx/lib/internal";
export class Example1 {
    @observable items : IObservableArray<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.visible = createObservableArray<string>([]);
    }
}
```

Result:

> Expected 2-4 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) observablearray.d.ts(41,
>   84): An argument for 'enhancer' was not provided.

Why I need this? Because I want to use the replace() method of the observable array:

```
 this.items.replace(newItems);
```

To allow this, `items` must have IOvservableArray type. Otherwise I'll get this error:

> Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

Of course, I can always do this:

```
(this.items as IObservableArray<string>).replace(items);
```

But that is very ugly, considering that I may want to replace all elements at multiple places in my code. It is also not type safe. If we don't care about type safety then it is shorter and not worse to do:

```
(this.items as any).replace(items);
```

But that is not the most beautiful code either. The `IObservableArray` was exported, so I guess there should be a correct way to use it and ensure type safety. But how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often use this pattern when declaring observable arrays:

```js
readonly items = observable<string>([]);
```

Does this accomplish what you need?

Comment: Where does that observable comes from? If I use `import { observable } from "mobx";` then `observable<string>[]` results in `'observable' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

Comment: Oh I see now. The type must be `IObservableArray<string>` but for the construction I need to use `observable<string>(array)`.

Comment: Yep, that's the trick. Sometimes I think it's not the most obvious API in the world, but it does work.

Comment: Why readonly is must??  what is the workaround if we use decorator instead of observable([ ])?

Comment: Readonly prevents you from accidentally setting the property instead of replacing it's items. If you overwrite the property then it becomes a different object, and observers of the previous array will not react to changes in the new array.